# Importing nativescript-local-notifications error on android

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am currently trying to import the plugin nativescript-local-notifications.
This plugin allows us to create local push notifications on the go without having to use a server.

The error down below is what I get when I start the application with:

```
var LocalNotifications = require("nativescript-local-notifications");
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.yeagger.app/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerCallbacks' of undefined

Is this a issue with the plugin or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the issue in github I found out that cleaning the entire project helps. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications/issues/108

I had already done this previously but at the same time I removed and added several other plugins. This could've conflicted with local-notifications.

After doing this for a second time it did work out.

> tns platform clean android